# Can not open jar file from Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I can not open a test case file that is exported before from selenium ide as jar file
Steps:

1)open selenium ide and record a test case

2)export test case as jar file

3)close selenium ide

4)open again selenium ide

5)file->open->file.jar

It will show you the following error : error loading test case no command found

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The default format to save Selenium IDE recordings is HTML. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" />
<title>selenium</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">selenium</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/wiki/Main_Page</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=searchInput</td>
    <td>selenium software</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=searchButton</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//div[@id='mw-content-text']/div/ul/li/div/a/span[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

That file can be loaded in Selenium IDE (the option File->Open), but not the JAR. More info [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp).

Comment: yes but my problem that I need to modefy the code.In html I can not write a script for example i need to read a text box and make sure that is correct so I need to write in java or python not in html